# How to store internal Laravel links in database

Tags: laravel

I am wondering how is the best way to store link like route('index') in the database, so if I change the url structure to not edit manually all links in the database.

What is the best practice for doing that on Laravel ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you please give more details? Why do you want to store links in the database?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir i have some articles, which contain links to my website. how should i store that information ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead try to [name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes) your routes, **use named routes** then you can change url whnever you want because routes are referenced by name

Answer (score 0):

wooot don't do this ! The helper "route" is made not to store all routes in database ! so don't store routes in it !

You have to think of your structure before doing anything else, your route file is the base of your app.

Use the "namespace", "prefix" and "name" functions from your Route::class to organize them, but never store it !

Comment: but i have some articles, which contain links to my website. How should i store that content ?

Comment: if you want to make links FROM your laravel, and TO another website, then store the full URL in your db as a string for exemple, and then just do a <a href="{{ $my_link_stored_in_db_as_string }}">my link</a>
if you want to make a link FROM laravel TO THE SAME laravel, then dont store anything, just use route helper

Comment: i am talking only about internal links. If i store the code in the database like this <a href=""{{ route() }}">link</a>, it display the link as "http://XXX/%7B%7B%20route()%20%7D%7D"

Comment: Then i don't got your problem... If it's internal links, all is based on laravel's routing system... 

If it's a static page, the route it to function which only return a view. Ikf it's a page with data stored in DB, then use route->get() with an {id}

Comment: the code i store in the is raw HTML code and route() is a PHP function. When i load the HTML code from the database, the Laravel Blade template does not understand route() as a PHP function. That's the problem

Comment: but dont store "route()" in your database ^^
do something like : 
$myRoute = route('your-route-name');
and then store $myRoute